# Zabbix, naming hostname in templates

Tags: zabbix

Initially, I wanted a way to change when I receive a notification for free hard disk space, which I have successfully done. However, I would like to implement this rule on one of the existing templates rather than individually add it to each host. However, when I do attempt to add the trigger by using the expression {hostname:vfs.fs.size[drive:,pfree].last(0)}<5, I am confused as to what to put as the hostname, since I am trying to put this in a template for multiple hosts.

I have tried to name it the template name that consists of the hosts, but have been unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger are associated with hosts they reference items from. To create a trigger "in" a template, reference an item from that template like so:

```
{template_name:vfs.fs.size[drive:,pfree].last(0)}<5
```

Comment: I did try that, it gives me the error "Incorrect item key "vfs.fs.size[drive:,pfree]" provided for trigger expression on "template 2"... where drive is a letter (H: , etc). I doubt it, but is the space in the template name a problem?

Comment: You have to provide the template name exactly as in the template properties - best is to copy-paste it. Of course, make sure an item with the exact same key exists in that template.